# Grub package configuration error on each and any software update

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub

Sometimes ago I had to restore Linux boot after Lenovo (v580 laptop) Windows 8 system recovery button pressing (just a stupid mistake). I followed this guide then http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245. Though I'm able to boot from Linux partition now on each software update (any software) I can see error which I can reproduce by following command execution:

```
mypc html # dpkg --configure grub-efi-amd64-signed
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.34.2+2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.1) ...
grub-install.real: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

I tried to reinstall `grub-efi-amd64-signed` package but that didn't help.

I'm using Linux Mint 17 64-bit

**UPDATE**

In BIOS it is set to boot Legacy+UEFI (Legacy first).

Currently installed grub packages:

```
mypc html # dpkg -l grub\*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-====================================-=======================-=======================-=============================================================================
un  grub                                 <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  grub-common                          2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.1   amd64                   GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
un  grub-coreboot                        <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-doc                             <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-efi                             <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  grub-efi-amd64                       2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.1   amd64                   GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-bin                   2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.1   amd64                   GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 binaries)
iF  grub-efi-amd64-signed                1.34.2+2.02~beta2-9ubun amd64                   GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)
un  grub-efi-ia32                        <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-efi-ia64                        <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-emu                             <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-ieee1275                        <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-legacy                          <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-legacy-doc                      <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-linuxbios                       <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-pc                              <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-xen                             <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub-yeeloong                        <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
un  grub2                                <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
ii  grub2-common                         2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.1   amd64                   GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
ii  grub2-theme-mint                     1.0.9                   all                     Grub2 theme for Linux Mint
```

Comment: Does your laptop boot with UEFI? That file is from a legacy-BIOS Grub package. What Grub packages do you have installed? (`dpkg -l grub\*`)

Comment: Thank you for your response Gilles! I've updated my question with that info.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of issue on a dell latitude E7450. I simply ran

```
    sudo apt-get install grub
    sudo apt-get autoremove
```

from a standard shell and that did the trick.